# Travel insurance (and flight tickets) for Long Term Schengen Visa

Tags: working-visas, schengen, europe, luxembourg

I am going to apply for a Long Term Schengen visa soon for a job I am going to start in Luxembourg. And I am unable to determine whether I need to get travel insurance or not. The [VFS website](https://vfsglobal.com/Luxembourg/India/long_term_documents_required.html) says I do need Schengen travel insurance for a minimum duration of 3 months, but, on the other hand, travel insurance companies have a clause about not settling claims before the traveller's return to India. This doesn't make any sense since I am applying for a long term visa.

I also have a similar doubt regarding flight tickets. I already have my 'Authorization to stay' issued by the Luxembourgish immigration department. So, is it necessary to present dummy/actual flight tickets?

Can anyone share their experience of applying for a Long term Schengen Visa? And tell me about what documents are actually necessary to get the Visa?

Comment: Please consider posting an answer on the authority of your experience after your application has been processed.  I will not be offended if you accept it instead of mine :-)

Comment: I received a long term visa from Austria recently. They requested travel insurance from me but that was furnished by my employer (I'd recommend asking them). As for tickets, they were ok with me presenting them with a one-way flight.

Comment: I finally went with everything on the checklist to avoid any troubles.

Answer (score 2):

Indeed, VFS seems to be mistaken.  The Luxembourg government [mentions travel insurance and transportation tickets or reservations only for short-term visa applicants](https://guichet.public.lu/en/citoyens/immigration/plus-3-mois/ressortissant-tiers/demarches-communes/entree-visa.html).  Perhaps you should complain to VFS using the details on [their contact page](https://vfsglobal.com/Luxembourg/India/contact_us.html) before you submit the application.

Answer (score 0):

As you're taking up employment in Luxembourg, you will be insured through social insurance automatically. If they still insist on proof of insurance for the first months, you could get something like an expat health insurance. Costs should be somewhere between 40 and 100 euros per month.

Also keep in mind that the VFS does not actually process applications, you can always insist on submitting the application as they are most likely required to accept it. If documents are missing they should inform you and in the end what the immigration authorities in Luxembourg say actually counts.

There is not Long Term Schengen Visa btw. Long term visas are all national visas and not issued according to Schengen rules.